# Estoy intentando descartar un modal de bootstrap usando Angular 6 cuando el servidor reciba los datos

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, angular, modal

Pues bien, este es el componente donde estoy intentado crear todo el contenido. Es un crud que guarda los datos cuando y lo que quiero es que el modal desaparezca.

Este es el html del componente:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="table-wrapper">
      <div class="table-title">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h2>Codigos De <b>Acceso.</b></h2>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <a href="#addProductModal" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons">&#xE147;</i> <span>Agregar nuevo codigo</span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='col-sm-12 pull-right d-flex flex-row-reverse'>
        <div id="custom-search-input">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar" aria-label="Input group example" aria-describedby="btnGroupAddon2">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnGroupAddon2"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='clearfix'></div>
      <hr>
      <div id="loader"></div>
      <div id="resultados"></div>
      <div class='outer_div'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Modal HTML  -->
  <div id="addProductModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <form #dataForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addData(dataForm)">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Añadir Codigo</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" id="dismiss" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Código</label>
              <input type="text" name="code" class="form-control" #code="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="dataService.selectedData.code" required >

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Dirección</label>
              <input type="text" name="direction" class="form-control" #direction="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="dataService.selectedData.direction" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Comentario</label>
              <input type="text" name="comment" class="form-control" #comment="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="dataService.selectedData.comment" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Tech #</label>
              <input type="number" name="tech" class="form-control" #tech="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="dataService.selectedData.tech" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancelar">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Guardar datos">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="center">

  </div>
```

Y este es el archivo de typescript:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Data } from '../../models/data' // La ruta puede ser distinta.
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-datas',
  templateUrl: './datas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datas.component.css'],
  providers: [DataService]

})
export class DatasComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  addData(form: NgForm) {
    this.dataService.postData(form.value)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.resetForm(form);

      })
  }

  /*
  close(form?: NgForm){
    if
  }*/

  resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if(form){
      form.reset();
      var dismiss = document.querySelector('#addProductModal');
      console.log(dismiss);
      this.dataService.selectedData = new Data();
    }
  }

}
```

Este es el servicio

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Data } from '../models/data';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  selectedData: Data;
  datas: Data[];
  readonly url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/datas';

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
    this.selectedData = new Data()
  }

  getDatas() {
    return this.http.get(this.url);
  }



  postData(data: Data) {
    return this.http.post(this.url, data); // En vez de "Data", escribes "data"
}

deleteData(_id:string) {
    return this.http.delete(this.url + `/${_id}`); // En vez de "data._id", escribes "_id"
}


  putData(data: Data) {
    return this.http.put(this.url + `/${data._id}`, data);

  }


}
```

Como ven, ese último método se llama resetForm, he intentado limpiar el formulario cuando se envíen los datos y lo he logrado, pero lo que necesito es que el modal se descarte. Alguien tiene idea?

Comment: ¿Quieres hacerlo desde el backend? O ¿antes de enviar el formulario? O ¿al recibir la respuesta aceptada del formulario?

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez Una vez que envíe los datos y reciba la respuesta de que todo fue correcto. Yo tengo el código del backend y estoy enviando bien los datos, solo me falta descartar el modal.

Comment: Pero donde recibes tu respuesta aceptada del formulario, supongo que debes agregar ese js

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez no no, envío los datos pero no recepciono respuesta del servidor ¿Qué tal si puedo mandar los datos sin recibir respuestas y así cerrar el modal? Acabo de actualizar la pregunta y he agregado los servicios que envían datos al servidor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi consejo es que utilices la modal como referencia desde un objeto de jQuery instanciándola en el `ngAfterViewInit` de tu componente (debido a que bootstrap se entiende mejor con jQuery que con JS puro).

Ver https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/modal/#methods

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    $('#addProductModal').modal({
        keyboard: false
    });
}
```

De esta forma, en tu método puedes usar `$('#addProductModal').modal('hide')` para ocultarla

```
resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if(form){
        form.reset();
        $('#addProductModal').modal('hide');
        // console.log(dismiss);
        this.dataService.selectedData = new Data();
    }
}
```

Aún así, tratándose de una aplicación con Angular; lo mejor que te puedo aconsejar es usar [ngBootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples), que es el módulo (o conjunto de módulos) de bootstrap pero en términos de Angular

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano. Probaré ambas opciones.